# A single set can be said to be pairwise disjoint with itself, right?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From the definition I've been given:

> A collection of sets $\{A_\alpha : \alpha \in I\}$ is said to be pairwise disjoint if the following is satisfied: For all $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\in I$, if $A_\alpha \cap A_\beta \ne \emptyset$, then $A_\alpha = A_\beta$

In the case of one set, $A_1$, which is nonempty, we have $A_1 \cap A_1 = A_1$ and $A_1 = A_1$ so it satisfies the condition above. I just want to make sure this is a common understanding and not just a mistatement of the definition.

Comment: That is my understanding.  I like the definition "if $\alpha \neq \beta$ then $A_{\alpha}  \cap A_{\beta} = \varnothing$" better, but this is equivalent.  In your case, you can never meet the assumption, so it's vacuously true.

Comment: A collection of sets containing a single element (set) is pairwise disjoint because every time the intersection of two sets from the collection is non-empty the sets are identical (i.e. the same one).

Comment: The other way to think about this is the contra-positive (I think that's the term): A collection of sets is NOT PAIRWISE DISJOINT if there exists (at least) two sets $A_{\alpha}$ and $A_{\beta}$ such that $\alpha \neq \beta$ and $A_{\alpha} \cap A_{\beta} \neq \emptyset$.  But, with a single element this can never happen, so it is pairwise disjoint.

Comment: If in a collection containing one set you were able to find two sets, I'll be happy to show that the sets are pairwise disjoint. in other words the property in this case is vacuously true.

Comment: As an aside, I think this also needs to be true if it is true that every open set can be represented with a union of pairwise disjoint open connected sets, and a set is connected if it can't be represented by two disjoint nonempty open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct definition is :

> A collection of sets $\{A_\alpha \ : \ \alpha \in I\}$ is said to be pairwise disjoint if the following is satisfied: For all $\alpha, \beta \in I$, if $A\alpha \cap A \beta \neq \emptyset$, then $\boxed{\alpha= \beta}$

Yet, it is a clumsy way to formulate it. I hence prefer the nicer :

> A collection of sets $\{A_\alpha \ : \ \alpha \in I\}$ is said to be pairwise disjoint if the following is satisfied: For all $\alpha, \beta \in I$, if $\alpha \neq \beta$, then $A_\alpha \cap A_\beta = \emptyset$.

And yes indeed the family $\{A_1\}$ is pairwise disjoint **but** the family $\{A_1, \ A_2\}$, where $A_1 = A_2$, is not pairwise disjoint.

Hence, the answer to the question as stated in the op title, namely

> A single set can be said to be pairwise disjoint with itself, right?

is no.

Comment: That's an interesting distinction between indices and their referent sets. That makes sense though and I see the problem with how I phrased the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, reading your excellent answer made me realize that the original question assumes every collection of sets is indexed. And I really don't know if that is standard or not. You can always index an unindexed collection with itself, but having "duplicated elements" requires the indexed version. I am totally unsure how most people handle this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question in your title is "No" - a single set is not pairwise disjoint with itself. In fact, that "with itself" part is confusing, and not good mathematical language.

However, a *collection of sets* containing just a single set is pairwise disjoint, for the vacuous reason that you can't find any pairs of sets in it.

We're really strict about these uses of language in math, and neglecting to do so can lead one to some serious mistakes. As another example, the number of elements in the sets $\mathbb Z$ and $\{\mathbb Z\}$ are drastically different.

Comment: What about saying "One set can be pairwise disjoint" then, (since a collection of sets is also a set)?

Comment: "Pairwise disjoint" is a property of sets that contain sets. If your set doesn't contain other sets, you can't be intersecting them to check disjointedness....

Comment: The term "collection" is mostly a short hand for sets whose elements are other sets. Serious set theorists are happy just calling them all "sets", but many math folk like using the word "collection" to remind them where they are on the hierarchy of sets.

Comment: If you're looking for the proper language to express your idea, I'll suggest "A collection containing just a single set is pair-wise disjoint, vacuously.".

Comment: Thanks that's helpful

Comment: (Oh, and when I'm using the word "contain" here, it means "has as an element", not "has as a subset".)

Answer (score 1):

The only set that is disjoint from itself is the empty set; a nonempty set is *not* disjoint from itself.

The definition you have for a pairwise disjoint collection of sets refers to an *indexed* collection that may contain duplicates (i.e. different indexes $\alpha,\beta$ with $A_\alpha=A_\beta$), and it considers the collection to be pairwise disjoint as long as any two *unequal* members are disjoint from each other.

An alternative definition for indexed collections would require that $A_\alpha\cap A_\beta=\emptyset$ whenever $\alpha\ne\beta$. The difference is that this disallows duplicate nonempty members.

Comment: How would you define a pairwise disjoint collection then?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out it's the *COLLECTION* of sets that is "pairwise disjoint".  That the sets within the collection.   So the *collection* $\{A\}$ is pairwise disjoint.  But that says nothing about whether $A$ itself is pairwise disjoint.  For $A$ to be pairwise disjoint the term "disjoint" must apply to the elements of $A$.  i.e. $A$ must be a collection of sets.  Now if $A$ is a collection of sets we have no idea how many set elements it has nor which of them are disjoint from each other.

So concl:  Yes, a collection $\{A\}$ of a single set is by definition pairwise disjoint. (Because $A\cap A \ne \emptyset \implies A=A$... [in fact "Kittens eat purple dinosaurs" $\implies A=A$ and $5$ is a prime number $\implies A=A$])

But, no, a set $A$ may or may not be pairwise disjoint. ( $A= \{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}$ is.  $A = \{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$ is not.  And for $A = \{apple, bannana, cantalope\}$ the question is meaningless.)

Once again, this comes down to a *set* (or a "collection") being a different thing with entirely different properties than its elements.  There are are just different animals altogether.